# Easy Linux Bash Script

Tags: bash

I know this is probably really easy and I am just putting to much thought into it but I need to create a Bash script that will convert Celsius to Fahrenheit with this equation:
    `f = (9/5)c+32`

How would I do this? Using just `expr` doesn't work because it won't use floating point. How do I do this equation? Using `bc`?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use bc try this :

```
echo "9*$c/5+32" | bc -l
```

Comment: also: `bc -l <<< "9*$c/5+32"`

Answer (score 1):

You (normally) don't need floating point arithmetic for this to work, if rounding errors are not critical and you don't need floating-point precision:

```
expr 9 '*' $c / 5 + 32
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be the easiest, I believe:

```
echo $(($c*9/5+32))
```

(and yes, floating point will be lost, you may add a couple of zeros and work on the string, tho).

Answer (score 0):

```
xdg-open "http://www.google.com/search?q=${TEMP}+C+in+F"
```

Too silly?  Check out http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/floating-point-math-bash